# SQL exclude weekends and public/bank holidays

Tags: sql, datetime, amazon-redshift

In my table I have a column full of dates. All the dates are from the start of 2021 till now only.

I'm currently using this code to get a count of the distinct timestamps:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT TRUNC(order_timestamp))
```

Is there anything I can add to this code or after to exclude the weekends?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ignore the weekend days using:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN DATE_PART(dow, TRUNC(order_timestamp)) BETWEEN 1 AND 5
                           THEN TRUNC(order_timestamp)
                      END)
```

`DATE_PART()` returns the day of the week starting with `0` for Sunday.  So weekdays have values between `1` and `5`.